# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. From trying to add scanner input values to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, out-of-memory

Not sure why I'm getting this weird error, but the program does not compile either so there must be something wrong with the while loop I made for the scanner. I've never seen this particular error.

private ArrayList gradeList;

```
public GradeDistribution() {
   this.gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public void addGrades(Scanner reader) {
    int grade = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    while (true) {
        if (grade == -1) {
            this.printGrades();
            break;
        } else {
            this.gradeList.add(grade); //the error points to this line
        }
    }
}
```

I did not include the printGrades() method but I assure you it is not the source of the problem. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong as everything seems like it should work. The ArrayList is initialized so I know it's not that...

Answer (score 5):

You need to move:

```
int grade = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
```

inside `while` loop.

Otherwise you have infinite loop that tries to infinitely add value of variable `grade` to `gradeList`. This increases allocated size on every iteration and when it exceeds limit exception is thrown.

When you move `int grade = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());` inside loop it ([`reader.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)) will stop loop until user hits enter.

After change your code will become:

```
public void addGrades(Scanner reader) {
    while (true) {
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (grade == -1) {
            this.printGrades();
            break;
        } else {
            this.gradeList.add(grade); //the error points to this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OF COURSE! It's kinda frustrating since this has been very obvious to me in the past; my work has been plateauing this past week. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your problem you should accept it. Tick on the left hand-side.